# How can a detergent "designed for sensitive skin" warrant the "corrosive" hazard symbol?

Tags: safety, soap

The dish-washing detergent, which you can find an image of [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqzsg.png), has the following hazard symbol on its back:

[image: Hazard symbol for corrosive]

On the back, it additionally says that if it comes in contact with the skin, you should immediately wash with lots of water, however the detergent also says "specifically developed for sensitive skin" on the front.

How can these two statements make any sense together? Are the chemical regulations that it has to follow just too on-the-safe-side, or what is going on? If I google up its safety data sheet in my local language, it contains the following phrasing:

> When handling chemical products, chemical resistant, impervious gloves complying with an approved standard should be used at all times if a risk assessment indicates the need for. (translated from Danish)

It also contains:

> Personal protective equipment for the body should be selected on the basis of the task to be performed and the risks involved and should be approved by a specialist before handling this product. (translated from Danish)

So my question is, why does a product like dish-washing detergent that is developed for sensitive skin need these kinds of warnings?

Edit: Image of the back can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tWvn.jpg).

Comment: Can you provide an image of the back of the bottle similar to the front?

Comment: I added an image. The one I have myself is not in English, but this picture appears to be the same product.

Comment: It has different properties at operation concentration and as a concentrate E.g. few % acetic acid is used as natural food additive as vinegar, while concentrated acetic acid would peel your skin away, as MaxW can testify.

Comment: The answer, putting on my legal hat (albeit, as disclosure, I have little to no professional legal credentials or training but have, at times, perform some legal research) is that the term 'sensitive skin' is simply not legally defined or has been adjudicated in the courts.  So, from a legal perspective, no contradiction here.

Comment: If you post your answers as a comment, I can't accept them.

Comment: Even in the light of @Poutnik comment - which must be the answer, this is hilarious :) However, azulene (in chamomile) is a soothing and decongestant principle entering eyedrops formulation. Working with it I've discovered that it is also, perhaps not antiriots police level, a terrible really terrible lacrimator! Paracelsus at work, again. 5 ml to a l'iter, it probably means that is specifically less aggressive than other products. Pity is that for assessment of bullshit like this animals are used.